# TSQL create ragged hierarchy from flat structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider this table:

```
declare @table as table (
    GL_Group_Code   varchar(8),
    GL_Branch_Code  varchar(8),
    Account_Number  varchar(4),
    GL_Centre_Number    varchar(6)
)

insert into @table
select  '0100', '0110', '1200', 'S10118' union
select  '0100', '0110', '1580', 'S16053' union
select  '0200', '0210', '2050', '200049' union
select  '0200', '0210', '2050', '782844'
```

The desired outcome is a parent child relationship across the four source columns into:

```
declare @table_hier as table (
    Parent_ID   varchar(8),
    Item_ID     varchar(8)
)
```

With a relationship order of column 1,2,3,4 the result for the first row from the source table would look like:

```
null 0100
0100 0110
0110 1200
1200 S10118
```

The second row would be:

```
null 0100
0100 0110
0110 1580
1580 S16053
```

The relationship order can vary: 1,2,4,3 or 3,4 or 1,3,4

I'm thinking recursive CTE however late on a Friday I could do with little help.

Comment: Do you need to create a fixed or to have the structure on demand?

Comment: On demand really, could go with fixed however that requires maintenance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you can have id in your table and use table variable to store columns you want to get, you can do this:

```
declare @ord table (id int)

insert into @ord
values (1), (2), (4)

;with cte as (
    select
        t.id,
        c.value,
        row_number() over(partition by t.id order by c.id) as rn
    from @table as t
        cross apply (
            values
                (1, t.GL_Group_Code),
                (2, t.GL_Branch_Code),
                (3, t.Account_Number),
                (4, t.GL_Centre_Number)
        ) as c(id, value)
    where
        exists (select * from @ord as o where o.id = c.id)
)
insert into @table_hier
select
    c1.value as Parent_ID, c2.value as Item_ID
from cte as c1
    inner join cte as c2 on c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 and c2.id = c1.id
order by c1.rn

insert into @table_hier
select null, t.Parent_ID
from @table_hier as t
where
    not exists
    (
         select *
         from @table_hier as t2
         where t2.Item_ID = t.Parent_ID
    )


select * from @table_hier
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97631/6)</kbd>**

Or if you can store your data in the tables or temporary tables, you can use dynamic SQL solution:

```
declare @ord table (id int)
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

insert into @ord
values (1), (2), (4)

;with cte as (
select c.name, row_number() over(order by c.colid) as rn
from sys.syscolumns as c
where
    c.id = object_id('dbo.table1') and
    exists (select * from @ord as o where o.id = c.colid)
)
select @stmt =
    isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
    '(' + c1.name + ', ' + c2.name + ')'
from cte as c1
    inner join cte as c2 on c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
order by c1.rn

select @stmt = '
    insert into table_hier1
    select C.Parent_ID, C.Item_ID
    from table1 as t
        cross apply (
            values ' + @stmt + '
        ) as C(Parent_ID, Item_ID)
'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt

insert into table_hier1
select null, t.Parent_ID
from table_hier1 as t
where
    not exists
    (
         select *
         from table_hier1 as t2
          where t2.Item_ID = t.Parent_ID
    )

select * from table_hier1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0471/13)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
declare @table as table (
    GL_Group_Code   varchar(8),
    GL_Branch_Code  varchar(8),
    Account_Number  varchar(4),
    GL_Centre_Number    varchar(6)
)

insert into @table
select  '0100', '0110', '1200', 'S10118' union
select  '0100', '0110', '1580', 'S16053' union
select  '0200', '0210', '2050', '200049' union
select  '0200', '0210', '2050', '782844'

declare @table_hier as table (
    Parent_ID   varchar(8),
    Item_ID     varchar(8)
)

DECLARE @RelatonShip VARCHAR(4)

SET @RelatonShip = '134'

IF @RelatonShip = '1234'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table_hier ( Parent_ID, Item_ID )
    SELECT GL_Group_Code, GL_Branch_Code FROM @table 
    UNION ALL SELECT GL_Branch_Code, Account_Number FROM @Table
    UNION ALL SELECT Account_Number, GL_Centre_Number FROM @table
END
IF @RelatonShip = '1243'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table_hier ( Parent_ID, Item_ID )
    SELECT GL_Group_Code, GL_Branch_Code FROM @table 
    UNION ALL SELECT GL_Branch_Code, GL_Centre_Number FROM @Table
    UNION ALL SELECT GL_Centre_Number, Account_Number FROM @table
END
IF @RelatonShip = '34'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table_hier ( Parent_ID, Item_ID )
    SELECT Account_Number, GL_Centre_Number FROM @table
END
IF @RelatonShip = '134'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table_hier ( Parent_ID, Item_ID )
    SELECT GL_Group_Code, Account_Number FROM @table 
    UNION ALL SELECT Account_Number, GL_Centre_Number FROM @table
END

SELECT * FROM @table_hier
```